# Find an exact piece of html code in a html document

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to find an exact copy of html code in a document.

I have tried

```
$("#tabs-1").find('div:contains(a)').html()
```

HTML:

```
<div class="appointment" data-status="yes">
    <a class="app">Yuri G.</a>
</div>
```

Does jquery provide any function for this or do I have to use Regex?

**Update**: I have multiple divs with with class appointments, with same attributes in a different div container element.  I am trying to copy them to another place by drag and drop.  I want to make sure that copy does not already exist in the drag and drop place

Comment: Can you post more code and explain what part of that code you want to retrieve?

Comment: You seem to have too many `>` characters, or insufficient `<` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:contains` is for text, try using `:has` instead.

```
$("#tabs-1").find('div:has(a)').html()
```

Or if you want the entire div as a string, you need to use `outerHTML`:

```
$("#tabs-1").find('div:has(a)').prop('outerHTML')
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/SupSA/

Comment: @manoj: What do you mean "same result"?  What result do you want?

Comment: Cann we take the entire html code as string and find it somehow?

Comment: @manoj: What do you mean "find it somewhere"?  "Find" it where?

Comment: the a in has(a) is not "a" of html element ... a is "div class="appointment" data-status="yes"><a class="app">Gary Kasparov</a></div"......Is it wrong the way I am using?

Comment: @manoj: Can you please update your question with *exactly* what you are trying to do, and *exactly* what result you are looking for?

Comment: :I have multiple divs with with class appointments with same attributes in a different div container element. I am trying to copy them to another place by drag and drop. I want to make sure that copy does not already exist in the drag and drop place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14039/discussion-between-manoj-and-rocket)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `:contains` to find HTML, only text.

You should be using DOM searches, not text searches.  This code gets you the exact text in the `<a>` tag.  You can then compare that text to see if it's what you were looking for:

```
$("#tabs-1").find(".appointment[data-status='yes'] a.app").text();
```

That will get you the appointment div from which you can get whatever else you need from that.  Depending upon what you're really trying to find in that area of HTML, the above can be tweaked to get that.

If there are multiple appointment divs, then you can find the one that has the desired text, like this:

```
$("#tabs-1").find(".appointment[data-status='yes'] a.app:contains(Yuri G.)")
```

Comment: I have multiple copies of <code>$("#tabs-1").find(".appointment[data-status='yes']")</code>, so need to match the inner text and html also for finding the exact copy

Comment: Please describe what the real problem you're trying to solve is.  Also, I hope you don't have multiple `#tabs-1` objects as that is illegal HTML.  Once you have the desired appointment object, you can use JS to see if the text matches what you want.  The point here is that you should be using DOM tools, NOT HTML text matches.

Comment: I have multiple divs with with class appointments with same attributes in a different div container element. I am trying to copy them to another place by drag and drop. I want to make sure that copy does not already exist in the drag and drop place. Thanks for your help..

Comment: @manoj - I modified my answer to retrieve the text from the a tag in that structure or find the link with specific text.  You can then use your own JS code to see if that text is what you were looking for or if that is the object you wanted.

Comment: @jfriend000: not exactly what I am looking for but that helps, thanks

Comment: can we not convert the html code to string then parse the #tabs-1 div for that exact match?

Comment: @manoj - Matching multi-tag HTML with attributes you got from innerHTML is a very bad idea and next to impossible to do cross browser.  Different browsers, particularly IE do NOT return the same thing that was in the page. The right way to do it is find traversing the DOM with DOM APIs and using selectors to find the right objects and then examine their attributes or text.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#tabs-1").find('div:has(a:contains("Yuri G.").app)')
```

(see http://jsfiddle.net/DB9Xh/)